# Meaning of noun + を挙げて

Tags: grammar, words

In *Last Period: Owarinaki Rasen no Monogatari* a village chief is imposing retirement on a male guide which relaunched turism in the realm, and he wants to made a group of beautiful girl guides; at one point, there is this sentence:

> 市を挙げて観光案内美少女グループを結成する

I can't find this construction on my grammars, but from what I was able to gather it means something like "-wide; As a whole; En masse"; I can't really understand it, though: what should it mean? That the whole city is creating that group guide? That group guide will cover the whole city? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is an odd usage of the following sense of [あげる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B/#jn-3185)

> 7 ㋒（挙げる）事を起こす。「兵を―・げる」

It means *to move/deploy (soldiers)*, and a more common use (in an extended sense) would be

- 奥州市は市を挙げて大谷翔平を応援している
- Oshu city as a whole supports Shohei Otani.

The basic meaning is, as you mentioned, *en masse/as a whole* and implies the organizational movement.

Another example:

- 会社を挙げて新製品の開発に取り組む
- The whole company works on developing a new product.

As for the sentence in question, 市を挙げて modifies 結成する - so it means the city as a whole creates the sight-seeing-guide-girls-group (probably as a part of strategy of promoting the city).

---

As pointed out in the comment,

> 6 ㋒（挙げる）力などを出し尽くす。「全力を―・げる」「町を―・げて応援する」

This seems to be the definition intended for the usage. I feel *-wide* is closer to the usage (市を挙げて does not sound like 市 trying hard), but at least it explains why I feel odd about 市を挙げて・・・結成する. Creating a group is not something one (or me at least) imagines requires to exhaust energy to accomplish. So collocation-wise, the sentence in question is not too idiomatic.

Comment: [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B/#jn-3185)では、６の㋒に「町を挙げて応援する」という例文があるので、これかな？と思ったのですがどうでしょう？

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why デジタル大辞泉 doesn't have it but スーパー大辞林 has this definition:

> ⑲ （「…をあげて」の形で）構成メンバーがそろって…するさまを表す。《挙》「国を―・げて歓迎する」「世を―・げて」

There's nothing odd about it. I believe 舉國 in Chinese has a similar meaning, too.